# 2021 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/election/1#questionnaire).**

---

Board & Card Games Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, 2021-10-18](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/election/1). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here’s how it’ll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until 2021-10-18 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The following two questions are guaranteed to be included:

  - How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
  - How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc. a question that you feel shouldn’t have been?
- The community team may also include the following three questions if the community doesn’t supply enough questions.

  - In your opinion, what do moderators do?
  - A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
  - In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. We exclude any suggested questions that are negatively scored.

  - We will post the final questionnaire on the [Election page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/election/1). Candidates will have the option to fill out the questionnaire, and their answers will appear beneath their intro statements.
  - This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

How will you handle questions that are *borderline* off-topic or otherwise low quality, and can't be trivially saved by an edit, but might be considered acceptable by a reasonable person (just not you)?  Does being a moderator change your action in any way on these questions compared to not?

Comment: What do you mean by borderline off-topic? Seems a bit strange to classify it as borderline but not able to be saved with an edit

Comment: The intent is to get at a question that the moderator thinks is *maybe* off topic, or *probably* off topic, but isn't *definitely* off topic.  Questions saved by edits are easily editable - what I'm aiming for is the common problem that arises when new moderators are either afraid to close questions they would have before cast close votes to close (but now are afraid to do so unilaterally if they're not 100% sure) - or move to close questions too quickly before there is a community consensus, in the case where there's no clear consensus.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but for me it a lot of it depends on why it is off topic or low quality then just being off topic/low quality.